# URL of Apple's map tiles

Tags: ios, mapkit

I tried to find URL of Apple's map tiles. I found some implementations using OpenStreetMap, but they look so different from Apple's map.

In case of Wi-Fi iPad, caching map tiles is needed for map apps that used outside home. I'd like to cache Apple's map tiles, but couldn't find the URL. After some tries, I found Apple's map tiles URL (http://gsp2.apple.com/tile?api=1&style=slideshow&layers=default&lang=ja_JP&z=%ld&x=%ld&y=%ld&v=9) to be used in iPhoto, but it also looks so different from current Apple's map. I'd like to cache map same as Apple's genuine.

Comment: do you want to take screenshot of any tile?

Comment: No, I don't want users to take a snapshot, but without prohibition code, they would do. If their behavior infringe someone's license, I had to code some logics to prevent.